# remove all after this char ")" or a specific word with regex

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

i have this string

```
The Walking Dead: Season 1 (DVD) tagged "the walking dead" 61 times
```

and i need to truncate this string, after this char ")" or delete the word "tagged" and remove all words after this.

Thanks at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what language you are using, but this should work.

use this regex:

```
\).*
```

And replace it with `)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*)(?:tagged)
```

The above regex will select everything before tagged.