# Remove all text from string after a sequence of words in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to assemble a UDF in Scala that takes a column from a data frame and manipulates it to remove HTML and other useless pieces of text.

The column I need to modify is very messy, sometimes there is HTML, sometimes there is not... Searching SO I have found a regex solution to [remove HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769454/scala-strip-all-html-tags-from-string-except-links)

what I'd like to accomplish now is to find a regex that can find a specific word in the text and delete all the text after that word.

I think I understand from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689439/remove-all-after-this-char-or-a-specific-word-with-regex) that the regex should be something like `\).*` if you want to remove all after `)`, so I am trying to adapt this to my case, unsuccessfully due to my lack of knowledge about regex.

I have strings like:

```
I am interested to hear from you, thanks   Sent from iPhone   other stuff I want to delete....
```

I'd like to retain the first part of the string up to "Sent from" excluded, so a perfect output would be:

```
I am interested to hear from you, thanks
```

What I have so far is something like:

```
 val toStringNoHTML = udf[String, String](_.toString
    // code from SO as linked above
    .replaceAll("""<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>""", " ")
    // delete all text after key word
    .replaceAll("""'Sent from'.*""", "")
    // remove all punctuation
    .replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}\n]""", " ")
    )
```

While the HTML gets remove, the "Sent from" and all the text after does not. Any hint how to adjust the regex to make it work?

**EDIT**
as pointed out in the comment, a small typo prevented my code to work, thanks for the help:

```
.replaceAll("""'Sent from'.*""", "")
```

should be

```
.replaceAll("""Sent from.*""", "")
```

Comment: just remove the `'` signs from around `Sent from`: .replaceAll("""Sent from.*""", "")`

Comment: `val toStringNoHTML = udf[String, String](_.toString.replaceAll("""<(?!\/?a(?=>|\s.*>))\/?.*?>""", " ").replaceAll("Sent from (.*)", "").replaceAll("[\p{Punct}\n]", " "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing multiple `replaceAll(pattern, blank)` I'd be tempted to start with an extraction.

```
val msgRE = "(.*>)?(.*)Sent from.*".r

val result = udfStr match {
  case msgRE(_, msg) => Some(msg.trim) // .replaceAll() can be added here
  case _ => None
}
```

Here the result is an `Option[String]` but that really depends on how you want to handle the non-matching input.

If more cleaning is needed after the extraction then `replaceAll()` can be added where indicated (or the extraction pattern can be better refined).